# canopy linux (64 bit) running error: can't open "Package Manager"

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, enthought

I install the Canopy 1.0.3(64 bit) in my Ubuntu 12.04(64 bit), but When I open the "Package Manager", it shows

> Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: (icui18n: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
>
> Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: (icui18n: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
>
> /home/cxyuan/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enstaller/enpkg.py:76: UserWarning: Expected to find /home/cxyuan/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages in PYTHONPATH
>     warnings.warn("Expected to find %s in PYTHONPATH" % path)
>
> .......
>
> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
>
> No JSON object could be decoded

Please help! Thank you

Comment: The traceback is incomplete.  Can you edit the question to show the full traceback? Thanks.  The warning at the top, can be ignored.